# Android - Custom font with border programatically

Tags: android, fonts, customization

My designer ask for applying this kind of font with border to native Android code.

[Screenshot - Font with border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG3aY.png)

And the original font can produce text like this:

[Screenshot - Font with original .ttf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhmBE.png)

Please advice me how to programatically create font like that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using font file inside your app?

Comment: @Jas yes I did. It's the .ttf file and I apply type face for it

Comment: Simply draw the font **twice**. Once bigger (the border) and once smaller (the inner part). Wit an x and y offset.

Comment: Thank you @FrankN.Stein. Your suggestion is completely right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just looks like a thick, heavy drop shadow was added. I'd experiment with `TextView.setShadowLayer()`. This looks to me just like a small positive y-offset, no x-offset, a black shadow, and a thick radius.

See [TextView.setShadowLayer()](http://file:///Users/coppock/GoogleDrive/Development/android-sdk/docs/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setShadowLayer(float,%20float,%20float,%20int))

Something like this:

```
myTextView.setShadowLayer(
    6f /* radius*/, 
    0f /* x-offset */,
    2f /* y-offset */,
    Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Thank you @kcoppock. Your suggestion is correct. I added 2 layers of shadow and it works fine. Again, thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

You can create own customize font with High Logic Font Creator software and then use it font in your app.

Save font in assets ( /assets/fonts/yourFont.ttf )

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yourFont.ttf");    // font saved in assets/fonts/
yourText.setTypeface(type); // yourText can be textView or EditText or etc.
```

you can download it from [here](http://dl3.downloadsoftware.ir/Software/1394/03/High-Logic.FontCreator.Pro.9.0.0.Build.1916.rar)

if need password, password  is: www.downloadsoftware.ir